# Intellij - after upgrade getting Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have an existing code that I was able to build before. I am not sure if the upgrade of Intellij was the cause, but I haven't been building the project for some time, and in the meantime I upgraded Intellij and now when I try to build a project, I get build errors that I never had before:

```
Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity
```

For this functions:

```
RoutingT -> findRouteData(ctx, id, null, null, null, false).firstOrNull() ?: emptyMap()

val routeSet = findRouteData(ctx, null, customerBusinessId, departmentBusinessId, null, viewChangeSet)

val deletedRouteSet = findRouteData(ctx, null, null, null, null, viewChangeSet, null, true)
```

And there is only one function `findRouteData`:

```
fun findRouteData(
    ctx: OrderCtx,
    businessId: Long?,
    customerBusinessId: Long?,
    departmentBusinessId: Long?,
    routingSetId: Long?,
    viewChangeSet: Boolean,
    countryAndPostalCode: Pair<String, String>? = null,
    isDeleted: Boolean = false
): List<Map<String, Any?>> =
    fetchRows(ctx,
        findRouteDataSql(viewChangeSet, customerBusinessId, departmentBusinessId, businessId, routingSetId, countryAndPostalCode),
        mapOf(
            "businessId" to businessId,
            "routingSetId" to routingSetId,
            "departmentBusinessId" to departmentBusinessId,
            "customerBusinessId" to customerBusinessId,
            "isDeleted" to isDeleted,
            "postal_code" to countryAndPostalCode?.second,
            "country" to countryAndPostalCode?.first
        ))
```

I also get:

```
Kotlin: Not enough information to infer type variable A
```

for this piece of code:

```
Triple(emptyList(), emptyList(), emptyList())
```

Why are this errors appearing now, when build was fine before. How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful to show us the code that has those errors

Comment: @IvoBeckers I have updated question with the code

Comment: Surely "Overload resolution ambiguity" is not the entire error message? It tells you which overloads it is ambiguous between, doesn't it? It should continue to say "All these functions match." then list all the overloads that match. Also, what type of `Triple` are you trying to create with `Triple(emptyList(), emptyList(), emptyList())`? Please state all the type parameters.

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project, please?